# Draw overbar with text above it in text-mode to group text

Tags: beamer, text-mode

I want to reproduce the text shown in the figure in a beamer presentation. Is there a simple way of reproducing it using Ti*k*Z/PGF or another package? Not exactly an overbar, but I do not know its actual name.

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us, what you try yourself so far! And search this site. Here is for sure a plenty similar questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, based on the `\overbracket` command from `mathtools`. I defined a `\textoverbracket` command, and added as a bonus `\textunderbracket`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\textoverbracket[2][]{\ensuremath{\overbracket[0.8pt]{\text{#2}}^{\text{#1}}}}
\newcommand\textunderbracket[2][]{\ensuremath{\underbracket[0.8pt]{\text{#2}}_{\text{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My title}

  \textoverbracket[Curabitur vehicula]{Lorem, ipsum}. Dolor sit amet, %
  \textunderbracket[Lacus vitae quam]{consectetur adipiscing}  elit

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is excellent; over and above what I was looking for, with the \textunderbracket as a bonus.